# ¿Por qué las pestañas de las preguntas a veces me salen de una forma y a veces de otra?

Tags: discusión

Cuando entro al sitio las pestañas de las preguntas me salen de una forma y luego cuando navego en el sitio que regreso para la pantalla de las preguntas, las pestañas me salen de otra forma. A continuación pongo las dos formas:

Primero me sale de esta forma:

[image: Primero me sale así]

Luego me aparece de esta otra forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si esto sea un bug o si sea normal que ocurra. Lo que sí puedo decir es que esta forma de mostrar el contenido me pierde un poco porque por ejemplo, a veces quiero visualizar las preguntas más recientes y en lugar de aparecerme la pestaña "Recientes", me aparece "Activas".

Answer (score 1):

La diferencia que observas se debe a que:

- el primer formato es el landing del sitio (la página de inicio).
- el segundo formato es el resultado de una búsqueda específica.

y están diseñadas con pestañas diferentes (es normal, no es un bug).

---

> a veces quiero visualizar las preguntas más recientes

Se pueden realizar [**búsquedas avanzadas**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/searching). Por ejemplo:

1. Preguntas recientes
   https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion
   <sub>*Si te interesa tenerlo accesible, agregalo a marcadores</sub>
2. Preguntas recientes, que no fueron cerradas y aún no han aceptado una respuesta
   https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20hasaccepted%3ano%20closed%3ano
3. Preguntas de [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) con votos >= 1 y aún sin respuesta, ordenadas por votos
   https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20is%3aquestion%20score%3a1%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano
4. Las preguntas que marcaste como favoritas en [apache](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache)
   https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapache%5D+infavorites%3A9130

---

**Nota:** No estoy diciendo que esté bien diseñado, simplemente que así funciona. Personalmente, me encantaría tener acá las pestañas del sitio en inglés.

Comment: Ok, gracias por la aclaración.